# IHostedService usable in Azure Functions App?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, background-service, asp.net-core-hosted-services

Regardless of whether we *should*, can we use `IHostedService` in an Azure Functions App?

Here is an attempt to register a hosted service (background service, specifically) as `IHostedService`:

```
internal sealed class Startup : FunctionsStartup
{
    public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Services.AddHostedService<ExampleBackgroundService>();
    }
}
```

The Functions App then throws the following exception:

```
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.InvalidHostServicesException: 'The following service registrations did not match the expected services:
  [Invalid] ServiceType: Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService, Lifetime: Singleton, ImplementationType: ExampleBackgroundService'
```

Comment: I ran into the same problem while trying to add the HealthCheck services to azure functions!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, this is not currently possible. There is some discussion on this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/5447#issuecomment-575368316):

> This would not play well with the dynamic scaling infrastructure. The scale controller is not aware of any logic running outside of the context of a function execution, and may scale in if it believes an application is idle. Customers would not have a reliable mechanism to keep that running unless they're artificially triggering function executions, and this would certainly generate confusion and support cases.
>
> The runtime and Functions infrastructure is not setup for compute use outside of the context of a function. Allowing the registration of custom hosted services would expose a feature that enables that, which would not play well with other infrastructure components (including fraud detection which could severely impact a customer's application)

The rest of the thread has more details and is worth checking out for more information.

Comment: Thanks @Donut! Follow-up question: I recall that the Microsoft docs concerning implementing a logger give explicit instruction to (cleverly) log to the hard drive, and then periodically move log entries to the log server in bulk. (Unfortunately I cannot seem to find this page anymore.) Is there a suggested alternative for this in Azure Functions?

Comment: @Timo I'm not aware of any alternatives, but that's not to suggest that there isn't one. Could try asking as a separate question or looking through the issues on the [Azure/azure-functions-host](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host) repo.

Comment: Come to think of it, the first point ("The scale controller is not aware of any logic [...]") seems to be remedied by cancellation tokens. Any background process should always honor cancellation (or risk being terminated mid-process). The scale controller could simply trigger shutdown, and give the instance 5 seconds before it kills it.

Comment: Come to think of it, most of what we have been discussing here applies particularly to a `BackgroundService` (the abstract class that helps you use `IHostedService` for background work). For many `IHostedService`s, which perform no continuous background work, the discussion is a non-issue. The Function may simply spin up and down, and an `IHostedService` will respond accordingly.