# Is there a way I can call a method from a class that is injected through dependency injection, right after the startup in azure function?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions, asp.net-core-hosted-services

I have an azure function whose startup looks like this

```cs
internal class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void ConfigureAppConfiguration(IFunctionsConfigurationBuilder builder)
        {

        }

        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Services.SomeExtensionMethod();// This will add few services to the service collection.
        }
    }
```

Consider multiple functions under a function app with this as the startup. Let one of the registered services in the `builder.Services.SomeExtensionMethod()` be `IBootstrapService`. Now I want to run a method in `IBootstrapService` right after the startup executes. Is there a way I can do this, since azure functions doesn't support IHostedService. **I cannot go with isolated function apps** because I have a lot of in-process functions which I need to migrate.

Answer (score 0):

Check my below findings helps to fix your issue

I can see there is an existing ticket in the GitHub regarding IHostedService implementation in Azure Functions .NET Core.

- As .NET Core supports [IHostedService](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting) NuGet Package, it will be supported in Azure Functions In-proces Projects.
- It can be implemented in builder.services configuration method and starting the function host and then other services when running is the good approach.

SO #[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59947132/ihostedservice-usable-in-azure-functions-app) - At that time Custom IHostedService implementation is not supported due to some issues and it is fixed later.

Also, I can see a similar issue regarding implementation support of IHostedService in Azure Functions.NET Core on MS q&a Forum [933834](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/933834/is-it-possible-to-run-a-custom-ihostedservice-befo) where @MughundhanRaveendran has provided the solution.

Comment: I tried it. Whenever I use IHostedService, I get this error in visual studio - 
```A host error has occurred during startup operation '45ab4e7f-1ef2-448b-bd40-99567b322bf3'.
func: Invalid host services. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost: The following service registrations did not match the expected services:
 [Invalid] ServiceType: Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService, Lifetime: Singleton, ImplementationType: k8senricherissue.TestHostedService, k8senricherissue, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.```

In Kubernetes I don't get any error but the app crashes.

Comment: Also the one mentioned in the MS q&a forum is about isolated func apps and not in-process ones. (Since it is mentioning creation of our own host instance which is not the case in in-process function apps)

Comment: Could you provide your function code snippets how you configured?

Comment: You can find my function app here: https://github.com/mavsankar/k8senricherissuerepro